# How to sort Kendo grid on different field?

Tags: javascript, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KenodGrid and I have field whose data is combination of two fields from the data. How would I be able to sort the Column based on the data of one field. Here is the column I have:

```
   {
            field: "Owner",
            filterable: false,
            sortable: true,

            template: function(data) {
                return data.OwnerFirstName + ' ' + data.OwnerLastName;
            }
        },
```

I want to sort the column on either OwnerFirstName or OwnerLastName but want to display both in the grid.

Comment: I think only changing field property to OwnerFirstName or OwnerLastName (based on which one you want to be sorted) will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Kendo grid sort table based on defined field for the column in configuration, using a template doesn't effect it. 
So if you add OwnerFirstName or OwnerLastName to your column field it will sort it will sort your table perfectly.

```
    columns: [
      { field: "OwnerFirstName",
       title:"owner",
            filterable: false,
            sortable: true,
            template: function(data) {
                return data.OwnerFirstName + ' ' + data.OwnerLastName;
            }
      },
    ....
  ]
```

Here is a working demo http://dojo.telerik.com/IPeVI

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it into 2 columns to be able to sort them apart :

```
            columns: [{
                field: "OwnerFirstName ",
                title: "Owner first name",
                filterable: false,
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: "OwnerLastName",
                title: "Owner lastname",
                filterable: false,
                sortable: true
            }]
```